# C# WebClient uploads file that is around twice as large as original

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-transfer

I am testing some file uploads using WebApi 2.0. I created a controller that has an upload method and I also created a console application to perform the upload. I am doing something wrong with my save operation that is causing the file to be around twice as large?

Below the screenshot shows the file I am uploading, and the file that gets saved from the server. Don't ask why that file, I just picked something in my Downloads folder.
[image]

Server Code for saving file:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Files")]
public class FileController : ApiController
{

    [Route("Upload")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFileAsync()
    {


        await ReadStreamAsync(HttpContext.Current, @"C:\Users\Bailey Miller\Desktop\FTP\WebsiteUploads\" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".txt");

        return Ok();

    }

    private async Task<bool> ReadStreamAsync(HttpContext context, string filePath)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true)))
        using (var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 4096, true))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filestream))
        {
            var readBuffer = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            await writer.WriteAsync(readBuffer);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Client code for uploading file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient _client = new WebClient();

        _client.UploadFile("https://localhost:44314/api/Files/Upload", @"C:\Users\Bailey Miller\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe");

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting .. .. ..");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You're using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` - classes designed for *text* - to handle what appears to be a binary file (AccessDatabaseEngine.exe). That's simply broken. Just use `Stream` instead of `StreamReader` and` StreamWriter`.

Comment: Can you post an updated version of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` - those are for *text*, and your content isn't text. Just use `Stream` instead:

```
private async Task ReadStreamAsync(HttpContext context, string filePath)
{
    using (var input = context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true))
    using (var output = File.Create(filePath))
    {
        await input.CopyToAsync(output);
    }
}
```

(I've changed the method to just return `Task` as the `bool` part seemed pointless...)

Comment: I tried with that and it worked only my server file was 1KB bigger than the original is there something else weird about the saving?

Comment: @BaileyMiller: Well I don't know whether `GetBufferlessInputStream` is actually what you should be using here - that was just taken from your post. Any reason you're not using `context.Request.Files[0].InputStream`?

Comment: I was following an example from another post on how to save files using a stream rather than byte array.

Comment: I think the difference is not actually real. Size on disk was the same, I think perhaps the length of the file name because of the GUID was the cause.

Comment: @BaileyMiller: So how were you looking at the size, if you previously said it was "1KB bigger than the original"? I would suggest you hash both files as a better way of checking that they're really correct...

Comment: @BaileyMiller: Well I'd expect that to show the correct size for any individual file. You should compare the two files carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145467/discussion-between-bailey-miller-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295877/webclient-too-many-automatic-redirections-were-attempted

Comment: @MickJagz: It's not clear that that's directly related to this answer. Please don't use comments as just a way of drawing attention to "vaguely related" (but only by the use of the same type) questions.